# Free draw on iPad and save as image to Filesystem / DB

Tags: java, php, html, ipad

Unfortunately there is no code example here, as my own knowledge and Google seem to have drawn a complete blank on the subject.

I am writing some software for a company that needs to create some on the fly sign off sheets, a bit like the DHL / UPS type POD's that get signed when you have a delivery.

Each of their 60 teams already carry iPads that they use with the software already written (by me, HTML, Java & PHP) to find the job, add extras etc.

When the job is complete, they have asked for a way that the end user can just use a finger to scribble a signature on the screen to act as proof of delivery.  Perhaps add some notes, but these can be a text field and easy to add.

I'm basically looking for a code base, or a script, or even a point in the right direction to somewhere that will allow free drawing on an iPad screen within a HTML / PHP (or java) environment and then that scribble be saved down as an image that can be added the the db (MySQL) either in the form of a link to a file or as the image itself in a blob, either works for me as I can always convert the blob image to a link and remove later so the db doesn't get too bloated.

There are a few ideas floating around if using C# but nothing I can find for HTML/Java/PHP.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you have written a web app, using HTML/CSS/JS that runs on the iPad and not a native iOS app. In this scenario you could use the [canvas Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) and JavaScript to let the user sign something.

TinyDoodle is an example using this: https://tinydoodle.appspot.com/

Comment: Thank you it was the "canvas" bit I'm not used to working with, have now been able to refine my google search and found this http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/ which has proved a perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you also to everyone who voted down my question ...... what was I supposed to do, not ask it ????